# How to remove and add columns to a table after a user search?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function Products() { 
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);  
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const columns = [ 
    { headerName: "Product", field: "product"}, 
    { headerName: "Name", field: "name" }, 
    { headerName: "Date", field: "date" },
    { headerName: "Type", field: "type", hide : true }, 
    { headerName: "Open", field: "open", hide : true }, 
    { headerName: "High", field: "high", hide : true }, 
    { headerName: "Percentage", field: "pct", hide : true }
]; 

useEffect(() => { 
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/all') 
    .then(res => { return res.json();
    })
    .then (data => { setRowData(data);
    })
}, []); 

useEffect(() => { 
  fetch(`http://localhost:8080/all?product=${search}`) 
    .then(res => { return res.json();
    })
    .then (data => { setRowData(data);
    })
}, [search]); 

return ( 
  <div className="Products"> 
    <p className="one">Select product</p>   
    <SearchBar onSubmit={setSearch} />
    <div 
       className="ag-theme-balham" 
       style={{ 
          height: "300px", 
        width: "600px" 
         }} 
    > 
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={columns} 
        rowData={rowData}
        /> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
)
function SearchBar(props) { 
    const [innerSearch, setInnerSearch] = useState(""); 
    return ( 
      <div > 
        <input 
          aria-labelledby="search-button" 
          name="search" 
          id="search" 
          type="search" 
          value={innerSearch} 
          onChange={e => setInnerSearch(e.target.value)} 
        />  
  
        <button 
          id="search-button" 
          type="button" 
          onClick={() => props.onSubmit(innerSearch)} 
        > 
          Search 
        </button> 
      </div> 
    ); 
  } 
};
```

I don't know if this is even a way to do it, but in my code I have two APIs, and in one of them I can search based on product only via the search parameter. But as seen in my column headers, by default I only want the first three columns to show in the table which are: **"Product, Name, Date".** The rest don't exist/are hidden.

But then once the user searches for a product and hits enter, the first three columns **"Product, Name, Date"** disappear and the next four appear only: **"Type, Open, High, Percentage".**

Is there any way to do this by somehow erasing/filtering/hiding the columns?

Comment: Maybe you could use slice(0,3) and slice(3,7) ?

Comment: But can that be applied to a search function? I've never used that before

Answer (score 0):

Make set of two columns based on your search then bind that column.

```
 const columns = [ 
{ headerName: "Product", field: "product"}, 
{ headerName: "Name", field: "name" }, 
{ headerName: "Date", field: "date" },
```

];

Bind another when searching based on the product search.

```
const columns1 = [ 
{ headerName: "Type", field: "type", hide : true }, 
{ headerName: "Open", field: "open", hide : true }, 
{ headerName: "High", field: "high", hide : true }, 
{ headerName: "Percentage", field: "pct", hide : true }
```

];

Comment: I tried that just before I made this post but it was displaying along with my first three columns even when I added another line for the second column to the AgGridReact table. How would I bind that to the actual search itself like you said?